# code to remember user input in a form when going back one page, when using session variables in php

Tags: php, html, session-variables

```
<?php
  $_SESSION['regName'] = $regValue;
?>

<form method="get" action="get_reg.php onsubmit="returnvalidateForm()" name="myForm" >
<input type="text" name="regName" value=""><br>
```

Then on get_reg.php

```
$regValue = $_GET['regName'];  
<?php  echo "<html>   
  our registration is: ".$regValue." ,
```

so when I go back to the first page the input is blank, I want that the input is shown there

Comment: first use this `session_start();` at top of your page (in every page where you use/create session)

Comment: Sidenote: Unbalanced quotes in `<form method="get" action="get_reg.php onsubmit="returnvalidateForm()" name="myForm" >`

Comment: Missing it for `action="get_reg.php` so it's `action="get_reg.php"`

Comment: Here are a few tutorials that will surely get you started in the right direction http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/sessions.shtml and http://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/ - *"Give a man a fish and feed him for a day. SHOW a man how to fish and will feed him for the rest of his life."* ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a simple function, there many ways to do

```
//at top of page dont forget to start session in both pages 
session_start();

function input_val($key, $remember = true) {
    $value = '';
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$key])) {
       $value = $_REQUEST[$key];
       //Store value in session if remember = true 
       if($remember) {
         $_SESSION['old'][$key] = $value;
       }
       return $value;
    }else{
      //Return session data
      return isset($_SESSION['old'][$key]) ? $_SESSION['old'][$key] : $value;
    }
}
```

here is your updated code

```
<form method="get" action="get_reg.php" onsubmit="returnvalidateForm()" name="myForm" >
<input type="text" name="regName" value="<?php echo input_val('regName') ?>"><br>
```

Then on get_reg.php

```
$regValue = input_val('regName');  //use above function to get value
<?php  echo "<html>   
  our registration is: ".$regValue." ,
```

Hope it helps, dont forgot to to clean up the session when done `unset($_SESSION['old'])`

Comment: so you paste the function on both pages?

Comment: yes it required, i will create a separate `functions.php` to store all helper function and then include it in both page after `session_start();`

Comment: Glad i helped, don't forgot to accept my answer @Tsg91

Comment: Hey, I just did, but I'm actually starting to notice a problem, it seems like by default is taking blank as input, I mean as soon as I run it, it will take the blank as input, I tried using a javascript for the validation for if the field is empty , but not even that works, even if put a placeholder, when I start the page the blank, takes over the placeholder

Comment: It's like the input from your function takes over all of the properties or attributes that I gave to the input tag

Comment: also is not remembering input on textareas

Comment: Ok I just did, let me know if you would like more info, basically id just like the input validation to work, and if possible to have your function working with textareas as well, here is the link to the paste bin http://pastebin.com/ZGvFhqsN

Comment: nevermind about the textarea, ive figured it out, only the input validation is the problem

Comment: dude forget about it, it turns out the validation works for textareas so I'll just make everything a textarea, and make it not resizeable if I want, thanks again, you've been of great help

Comment: For anyone interested, I just realized I was making the dumbest mistake ever with this function instead of  value="<?php echo input_val('regName') ?>" I had  value=" <?php echo input_val('regName') ?>" see the space after the quote , on the second one that was my issue